# Qt 4.8 compiling from ubuntu to windows

Tags: qt, mingw, qt-creator, qt4.8

I have a simple app that I can compile on the desktop for Ubuntu 12.04, but not for Windows. I installed the MinGW toolchain, both from synaptic, and the QT 64-bit package from [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/MinGW-64-bit).

I went to Tools-->Options-->Build, and manually added both the /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++, as well as the g++.exe from the link above (in the bin folder) as MANUAL_1 and MANUAL_2.

When I go to create a custom target however I am unable to select either Manual toolchain and it reverts back the standard GCC x86_64 linux.

What am I doing wrong?
I doubted the g++.exe file would work since that is a windows binary, but why does it not select the system mingw binaries?

Comment: Added Qt Creator tag, as this seems to be issue with that. What version of Qt Creator? You shoild probably try with latest, the whole thing got a re-design in a recent version.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you should check

- Your gcc version number
- Is your gcc path added to environmental variable?

I too found it very difficult to compile my MINGW Qt application in Windows, and after lot of research on net I found that qt4 works with gcc 4.4.0 MINGW. I downloaded qtcreator 2.1 from qt website and copy MINGW folder from qtcreator directory, copy that folder into my windows root directory then installed latest qt creator and qt4 sdk, 
Add path of gcc 
and finally qt creator compiles my code.